# Statically Reverse Engineering Shellcode - IDA to Ghidra

Tags: ida, disassembly, binary-analysis, ghidra, shellcode

I'm trying to follow along with this tutorial which is using IDA in it's example. https://0ffset.net/reverse-engineering/malware-analysis/common-shellcode-techniques/

Hash: 9d7e34250477acf632c6c32fc2c50d3b

In the example, after decryption of the stage 2 this is the result:
[image]
[image]

When I repeat the same steps with Ghidra I get the following result:
[image]
[image]

I've been following the assembly trying to see if I could figure out what when wrong or what is going on with no results yet.

While searching, I came across these references:
https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_139.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLT_(x86_instruction)

It would be appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction.

EDIT:
After Paweł Łukasik pointed out my error, it works:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from address `0x56` all your instructions seems to be off. And if you look closely it there is a pattern how much off they are from the original.

For example, at offset `0x58`, there's supposed to be `push edx` so the byte should be `0x52`, but you have `push esp` which is `0x54`. Since the article mentions that this part is encrypted with a xor (with a single digit key), let's see how those values are off

```
In [7]: 0x52 ^ 0x54
Out[7]: 6
```

So this is exactly the key mentioned in the article. If we compare the rest of those off instruction we will notice that they are off by the same value.

Conclusion - this part of code shown in Ghidra was not decrypted and should be preprocessed before analysis.

Comment: ugh, thanks, I totally overlooked that. I even went back but it did not clue in to me that I had included the key until your response.